# Php sort multiple array using concretely values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have array such as:

```
$arr = [
        0=>['note_id'=>1,'content'=>1],
        1=>['note_id'=>2,'content'=>2],
        2=>['note_id'=>3,'content'=>3],
    ];
```

And I have array of ids:

```
$ids=[2,3,1];
```

I need get new array from **arr** by using the sorting this array by value 'note_id' and array **ids**, so resut must be:

```
   $arr = [
            1=>['note_id'=>2,'content'=>2],
            2=>['note_id'=>3,'content'=>3],
            0=>['note_id'=>1,'content'=>1],
        ];
```

Are there any functions for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop both the arrays and  compare the keys of `$arr` with with the values of `$ids` and create your new array `$newArr`.

```
$arr = [
    0 => ['note_id' => 1, 'content' => 1],
    1 => ['note_id' => 2, 'content' => 2],
    2 => ['note_id' => 3, 'content' => 3],
];
$ids = [2, 3, 1];
$newArr = [];
foreach ($ids as  $id) {
    foreach ($arr as $keyArr => $item) {
        if ($id === $item['note_id']) {
            $newArr[$keyArr] = $item;
        }
    }
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [note_id] => 2
            [content] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [note_id] => 3
            [content] => 3
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [note_id] => 1
            [content] => 1
        )

)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/TJcIQ)